# I can't see the ip address using QHostAddress::LocalHost through UDP with QUdpSocket

Tags: c++, qt

i'm planning do a little app desktop with Qt Creator. I'm using QUdpSocket class to make a simple connection through UDP, in fact i used a test code i found on internet, but my problem is when i run the code and the console just show me the port and the message, not the ip address where come from the message. Could someone tell me what i'm doing bad?

[The source reference is this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QUdpSocket.php)

This is the header file:

```
#ifndef PRUEBAUDP_H
#define PRUEBAUDP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

/*#include <QNetworkDatagram>
#include <QHostAddress>*/


class pruebaUDP : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit pruebaUDP(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  void mensajeSocket();

signals:

public slots:
void readyRead();

private:
  QUdpSocket *udpSocket;
};

#endif // PRUEBAUDP_H
```

This is the source file:

```
    #include "pruebaudp.h"

pruebaUDP::pruebaUDP(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
  udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 1234);

  connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
          this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

void pruebaUDP::mensajeSocket()
{
  QByteArray dato;
  dato.append("hola");
  udpSocket->writeDatagram(dato, QHostAddress::LocalHost, 1234);
}

void pruebaUDP::readyRead()
{
  QByteArray buffer;
  buffer.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());

  QHostAddress sender;
  quint16 senderPort;
  udpSocket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, &senderPort);

  qDebug() << "Desde: " << sender.toString();
  qDebug() << "mensaje del puerto: " << senderPort;
  qDebug() << "mensaje: " << buffer;
}
```

and this is the main file:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "pruebaudp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  pruebaUDP prueba;
 prueba.mensajeSocket();

  return a.exec();
}
```

This is a input screenshot:

[image: the ip address isn't show]

Comment: Where is `Desde la direccion` in your program?

Comment: Why there is no `#include <QHostAddress>`

Answer (score 0):

You use same socket for sending and receiving.
Try to send data via other socket, i.e.

```
void pruebaUDP::mensajeSocket()
{
  QByteArray dato;
  dato.append("hola");
  static QUdpSocket * socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
  socket->writeDatagram(dato, QHostAddress::LocalHost, 1234);
}
```